# Event Source Polyfill, send parameters

Tags: javascript, server-sent-events

I am using Event Source Pollyfill : https://github.com/Yaffle/EventSource/blob/master/eventsource.js

I noticed that this pollyfill send a unique code like `r=5743466970371525`. I also want to send a parameter for every request/retry.

I did this:

```
user_time = 1407805878;
var sse = new EventSource('server.php?user_time='+user_time);
sse.addEventListener('message',function(e){
    var data = e.data;
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    // here I have updated user_time from responce
    user_time = obj['time'];
    console.log(obj);
},false);
```

But after changing value of `user_time` from response, still old time is sent.
I hope I need need to override `EventSource` url from prototype ?

I tried this to update `EventSource` url:

```
user_time = 1407805878;
var sse = new EventSource('server.php?user_time='+user_time);
sse.addEventListener('message',function(e){
    var data = e.data;
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);

    // here I tried to update URLe
    sse.url = 'server.php?user_time='+obj['time']
    user_time = obj['time'];

    console.log(obj);
},false);
```

So, please help me to send a custom parameter. The pollyfill I am using does this, but I cant figure out how to ?
Thanks

Comment: [The `url` parameter is read only](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource). I'm curious about this question, as the concept of EventSource is that the client **listens** for responses from the server. If you are constantly changing the URL to the server, it's essentially wanting to create a new EventSource object. Maybe what you want is a two-way communication method instead?

Comment: 1) You can use "last-event-id"; 2) You can use cookies; 3); you can close EventSource at "error" and create new object with new url